# Missing datagrid boundcolumn in production

Tags: c#, datagrid

Using visual studio and C#, I recently added a new bound column to a data grid and modified the stored procedure to pull the extra field.  When I debug it - it shows up fine and displays the data as I expect.  When I publish the website and copy the files to the web server, the column is no longer there.  It's a pretty straight forward setup.  I know the file is being copied etc.  What am I missing?

Comment: Chances are the code on the server is not consistent with your develpment machine. Check the webserver.

Comment: instead of replace the file(.aspx page which has datagrid ), first delete the file from server, then paste new file on server, and also try to remove the cache

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comments added above, make sure your added field exists on Production Database.

If it throws an exception that your code swallows up, you would never know.

Example:

```
private bool SomeMethod(string cmdText) {
  bool result = false;
  try {
    result = Query(cmdText);
  } Catch (Exception) {
    // Error occurred
  }
}
```

If you had the code above and had an error, you would never know.